# Disable "Back" & "Refresh" Button in Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, double-submit-prevention

I am doing web development. 
I have a page to do with credit card, which when user click "refresh" or "Back", the transaction will be performed one more time, which is unwanted.
This include Browser top left "Back" & "Refresh" button, "right click->Refresh/Back", press "F5" key.
This is to be done on certain cgi page only, not all of them.
Can this be done using Javascript? Or any other method?

Thanks,
sytee

**exact duplicate**: [How do I stop the Back and Refresh buttons from resubmitting my form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665399)