# Stop Refresh from Resubmitting Form

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi

I did my research and found this page:

[How do I stop the Back and Refresh buttons from resubmitting my form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665399/how-do-i-stop-the-back-and-refresh-buttons-from-resubmitting-my-form)

I would prefer if I could avoid using the Post-Redirect-Get pattern and instead have some variable change in the form when I submit it the first time. However, I don't know how this would be done because when you hit refresh the idea is you are resubmitting the form you just submitted. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid Post/Redirect/Get? It is the correct solution.

Comment: +1 it's the only solution I've known

Answer (score 3):

This is usually dealt with via a redirect after the POST request.  Clicking back will simply redirect the user away again.  I know you mention you want to avoid this but I can't see any valid reasons.

Answer (score 2):

When a browser is told to refresh, it re-sends the last request that it sent.  If the last request sent was a form submission, then the form will be re-submitted.  There's no way around that because that's simply how the model works.

To prevent undesired effects, you have to either:

- use post-redirect-get, so that the last request (the one that gets re-sent) will be one which reads the results of your form submission rather than the form submission itself
  or
- put an identifier in the form so that the re-submission can be ignored by the server (although the user will still see the "do you want to re-submit?" confirmation)

I am not aware of any other options and, given the way that "refresh" works, I don't really see how there could be any others.  Of those two choices, post-redirect-get gives the cleanest user experience and is the most theoretically "pure" use of HTTP verbs, so it is generally preferred and, IMO, the correct solution.

Comment: Good job on the explanation! Gave me a ton of insight, and changed me from doing a `render` in node, to a simple redirect

Answer (score 1):

Send a unique form identifier, such as a UUID, with the form, in a hidden field. Keep track of which UUIDs you've already seen (perhaps per-session, so your database doesn't grow without limit or need occasional trimming) and silently ignore re-submissions.

Comment: or cache the results for submissions and return what's cached when you get an already seen uuid