# Avoiding form resubmission in SPA (without P-R-G)

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, durandal, post-redirect-get

I have a Single Page Application (SPA) built with DurandalJS v1.2 that integrates with a payment gateway. The SPA will go off to the payment gateway's page by doing a normal form POST to their page.

Once the user has finished on the payment gateways page, the payment gateway will then do a form POST back to my SPA.

Since it's a POST, I handle it server side in ASP.NET MVC by rendering out a require.js module definition for the various form parameters being sent, and this module is then used in the view model that needs to handle the result.

This is all working fine, I handle the result, and then stay on the same SPA page. This is different to the typical web pattern of Post-Redirect-Get, since the SPA doesn't do any redirects.

The issue now is when pressing the browser refresh button, it's bringing up the browser's retry post confirmation dialog (which I don't want).

Is there a way to avoid this by using JavaScript, or is the PRG pattern the only way?

Note: It appears that changing window.location, document.location, as well as using history.replaceState all do not work (at least in Chrome).

Comment: Coincidentally, if I do refresh the browser and accept the form re-submission, since I do actually change the hash before this occurs, the URL my SPA enters in on refresh isn't the one that processes the payment gateway responses, and so it doesn't handle it a second time. However, the confirmation dialog is still an annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the payment gateway, then intercept the form submission (`<form onsubmit="...; return false">`), process the form fields from JavaScript instead of letting the browser send them to the server.

If you can't modify the payment gateway, then modify the `document.location` from JavaScript just after the POST back (e.g. by adding a `#`). If the user presses reload after this, the browser won't ask for confirmation.

Comment: It's being posted from another website, not on my page. I cannot modify the payment gateway, as it is a completely separate system.

Comment: I've added another idea.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I failed to mention I'd already tried changing the hash

Comment: BTW, changing the hash does solve the problem of not processing the result twice, see comment on original post.